# AWS SMS messages have stopped being received ONLY to US phones but works for other countries

Tags: amazon-web-services, sms, amazon-sns

We were successfully using AWS SMS messages sending to phones in India, Sri Lanka and USA and have been good for last 2 months. All of a sudden yesterday ONLY US phones are not getting the messages. Sending in the console says it was sent ok but we are not getting the messages. We are far from our $400 monthly budget.It is strange it is only US issue but we can send to other countries no problem. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Be careful that you do in-fact have that budget. Open an AWS support ticket right away though. They will be able to see what has happened. That credit can run out really quick actually. Also [Service Quota](https://console.aws.amazon.com/servicequotas/home) dashboard.